# How can I display the action of a database-linked form with sinatra?

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra

I have been working on a project in Ruby's Sinatra with ActiveRecord and MySQL and have ran into an error: part of my site is adding a link to the database and I want to show all of the links on the next page but for some reason I can not seem to find out how to express this. 
This is what I have so far:

```
get '/dashboard' do
   @site = Site.find_by text: params[:text]
   @sites= Site.all
    @newsite = Site.new ({:text => :text})
    @user = User.find_by_id session[:user_id]
    erb :dashboard
end
```

This is what ERB page looks like:

```
 <% @sites.each do |site| %>
 <h4><%=site.text.to_s%></h4>
 <% end %>
```

How would I solve this? Now my form works but it does not show anything after

Answer (score 0):

Your ERB code references a `@sites` attribute which you don't set in the controller.

If you set `@sites` in your ruby code to be an array of the Site records you want to show, then you should see something.

Comment: So if I determined an @sites then it would load? Would I say something like @sites= Site.all ?

Comment: Something like.  I'm afraid my ActiveRecord knowledge is a bit out of date.  Try it and see?

Comment: I tried it and didn't get an error, but it didn't show anything. Thanks for your help, though